# Importing Commerce Orders and Users

Tags: commerce

I am revamping a website which is uses [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). I want to actually mirror the website and work on it offline before bringing it back onto the server as the newer version.

Obviously while I am doing this there is likely to be orders made and new users registered.

How can I import these or somehow bring the revamped website upto date with all users and orders?

Can anyone see any other issues with doing this also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Commerce Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate)  and import your orders, and [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import users.

From Commerce Migrate project page:

> Commerce Migrate is a general-purpose migration framework extending
>   [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) Module for bringing
>   store information into [Drupal
>   Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce).

Also, there is a thread about this [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1156952).